# SymPy expand for MatrixMul

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

Is there any way to expand a `MatMul` object?

For example, I have the expression `(A*x+b).T*(A*x+b)` and I would like the output to be the following:

```
x.T*A.T*A*x+x.T*A.T*b+b.T*A*x+b.T*b
```

My code is:

```
from sympy import symbols, MatrixSymbol
A = MatrixSymbol('A',n,n)
x = MatrixSymbol('x',n,1)
b = MatrixSymbol('b',n,1)

(A*x+b).T*(A*x+b)
```

Which just outputs:

```
(x'*A'+b')*(x*A+b)
```

How can I apply something like expand() to this example?